# Как правильно обновить gitlab через docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

Есть рабочий gitlab ce 11.8.0, запущенный через docker-compose. Хочу обновить его до последней 13.x версии. В офф документации говорится про простой способ обновления через изменения версии в docker-compose.yml:

```
<...>
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up -d
<...>
```

Но при обновлении через пакеты важно переходить через промежуточные версии

> Five intermediate versions are required: the final 11.11, 12.0, 12.1 and 12.10 releases, plus 13.0.
>
> 11.5.0-> 11.11.8-> 12.0.12-> 12.1.17-> 12.10.14-> 13.0.14->13.2.10

Вопрос в следующем: для обновления gitlab через docker-compose нужно ли устанавливать промежуточные версии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная сложность всего процесса и необходимость в этих последовательностях лежит в плоскости миграции данных, а не в том, как именно (т.е. с докером или без) установлен gitlab, так что необходимость проходить через промежуточные версии при обновлении не зависит от того используется docker или нет.

Так что простой ответ - что обновление с пропуском версий это рискованно и не гарантируется - дан в [документации](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/):

> We cannot guarantee that upgrading between major versions will be seamless. It is suggested to upgrade to the latest available minor version within your major version before proceeding to the next major version.

Полный ответ там же и содержит много деталей почему и что нужно делать, но если в вкратце и самое главное, то последовательное обновление нужно, чтоб на каждом этапе перед переходом к следующему убедиться и дождаться, что все миграции данных текущего этапа успешно закончились.

Comment: ок, были сомнения, решил ещё раз утвердиться. спасибо за ответ :)